# Find the number of entries between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an online hotel booking system , Using php and mysql .
In my database scheme , table bookings refers to the booking dates .

The below shows some entries of bookings table :-

```
  id   id_item   the_date  

   1       1      2014-03-25

   2       1      2014-03-26

   3       1      2014-03-27

   4       1      2014-03-25

   5       2      2014-03-02

   6       2      2014-03-02

   7       3      2014-03-25

   8       1      2014-03-26

   9       1      2014-03-27
```

In the table , `id_item` shows room category .in i`d_item 1` there are two rooms.

In `id_item=1` there are two entries in between `25-03-2014 to 27-03-2014` .so two rooms are booked .

I want to calculate how many number of entries are in bookings

```
"where id_item =1 and the_date between 25-03-2014 and  27-03-2014 ".
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM bookings 
WHERE id_item = 1 AND the_date BETWEEN '2014-03-25' AND '2014-03-27'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select count(*) as total_booking from tbl_name where id_item=1 AND the_date BETWEEN '2014/03/25' AND '2014/03/27'
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mydate >= STR_TO_DATE('110321', '%y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        AND mydate < STR_TO_DATE('110321', '%y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's work fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM bookings WHERE id_item = 1 AND (date(the_date) BETWEEN '2014-03-25' AND '2014-03-27');
```

Comment: @Rahil Wazir .the abouve query display the total number of entries in the table . i want to calculate how many number of bookings done in id_item 1 and the_date between 25-03-2014 to 27-03-2014 .

Comment: how will you find this is booking room and this are all not ?

Comment: Above query only return count for what are the row have a id_item=1 and between those dates